# Trying to highlight cells based on other cells, row by row

Tags: excel, google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to use conditional formatting so that the cells in [green will highlight when they are NOT BETWEEN the values in the cells in orange](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdIZO.png), on a row by row basis. Seems like conditional formatting doesn't accept taking values from other cells when defining the rule and only accepts values or formulas. And if possible, a way to apply the rule down the list similar to filling formulas.

Comment: Conditional formatting does accept values in cells, but you have to use absolute addressing ie "=$A$1" and for not between that is a condition in the list in the Conditional formatting window.

Answer (score 1):

Just combine these two basic rules:

[image]

Into something like:

[image]

It comes down to:

A is not between B and C <=> (A<B) OR (A>C)

It results into this:

[image]

Both the values 1 and 5 are not in between of 2 and 4.